# Standards for representing real numbers in computers (other than floating point)?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, real-numbers, computational-mathematics, floating-point

Some year ago I made a small discourse and investigated some representations for real number approximation, for example quotient between integers, satisfying this equation

$$ax - b = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac b a \hspace{1cm} a,b\in \mathbb Z$$

or more general algebraic numbers satisfying

$$\sum_{k=0}^N c_k x^k = 0, \hspace{1cm}c_k\in \mathbb Z$$

Where for example all kinds of roots and other common irrational numbers then can be represented exactly (to whatever extent we allow to represent large enough integers). Today these are readily iteratively "calculable" by loads loads of numerical methods (turning them into for example floats or doubles if we would need that at some stage).

---

To my question, do there exist any standard or RFC or something similar for representations other than floating point standards for real numbers.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick that seems to be little more than just some rant by people who find the idea inconvenient and are excessively triggered by what they consider to be "misbehaviour".

Comment: Okay. So maybe he found more complicated alternatives inconvenient. I agree for most purposes it would probably be unnecessarily complicated. But I imagine mathematicians could benefit from such things anyway. What do I know, maybe they prefer calculating their values to arbitrary precision on their own...

Comment: @PeterSheldrick Yes what you describe does happen to some extent. But it depends heavily on the use case. There is still a lively research on video coding going on and also for still images most people working professionally with media know the drawbacks of sloppily coded jpeg which can give artifacts, and not being particularly scalable when sending to different devices et.c.

Comment: @mathreadler The answer to you question is "No". There are two floating-point standards, MIL-STD-1750A and IEEE-754 (2008). While there has always been sporadic research into alternative encodings of real numbers (logarithmic number system is an interesting one with some practical relevance, and John Gustafson's posit proposal is probably the most recent one), there are no relevant standard for these.

Comment: Ok good to know. About time someone made one.